# Cakephp - Change validation errors div structure?

Tags: cakephp

Is there any way of changing the validation error div structure? I want to insert an image just before the div.

Each error will be displayed inline with the input field, so I want to insert a left arrow image before the validation div.

Currently I am getting this:

```
<div class="input password required error">
<label for="StudentPassword1">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="data[Student][password1]" value="" id="StudentPassword1" class="form-error">
<div class="error-message">notempty</div>
</div>
```

I'd like:

```
<div class="input password required error">
<label for="StudentPassword1">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="data[Student][password1]" value="" id="StudentPassword1" class="form-error">
<img src='...' />
<div class="error-message">notempty</div>
</div>
```

How would you accomplish this? I'm guessing that I have to modify the core? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm guessing that I have to modify the core?

**No**.  If your app requires changing Cake's core you are likely doing something wrong.  Cake has a lot going on and it takes care of a lot of things for you.  This happens to be one of the things you can customize to your liking.

When you create your Forms with the `FormHelper` you can [specify default options for `input()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1639/options-inputDefaults) and one of those options includes [the HTML structure and class used to wrap error messages](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1401/options-error).

Comment: So I would have to add the $options['error'] to each and every input I create?

Comment: Check out the first link where you specify default options for `input()`.

Comment: So how would you go about inserting the image? add the html in the validation error and turn off html escaping?

Comment: It seems a bit hacky and tedious but I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I would just modify the CSS of the error-message class to include the image.

```
.error-message {
    background:url( path/to/img.png ) no-repeat top left;
    padding-left:40px; /* or whatever you need for the image to fit */
}
```

Comment: Yeah but what I want is a pointy arrow to the left that will contrast with the page background. Something like the ones here http://www.evelmerch.com/signup.php

Comment: Right. Add the image you have of the arrow to the CSS as shown above.

Comment: That would just move the content to the right, but the image won't be visible since the div has the same color of the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 
          'inputDefaults' => array('error' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                     'wrap' => 'label', 'class' => 'text-error'
                 )
           ) )
)); ?>
```

This will make you customize the error output.